# Does RMSD-based estimation conserve the estimated data distribution?

Tags: normal-distribution, estimation, rms, procrustes-analysis

Let's say I have two sets of paired points $\{x_i\}_{i=1..n}$, $\{y_i\}_{i=1..n}$ defined in an $N$-dimensional space and I want to use [the Kabsch algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kabsch_algorithm) to estimate the best rotation matrix / translation vector that transform each point in $\{y_i\}_{i=1..n}$ into its corresponding version in $\{x_i\}_{i=1..n}$ by solving the Orthogonal Procrustes problem based on the RMSD  (root mean squared deviation) criterion:

\begin{equation} 
R = \arg \min_{R} \|R Y - X {\|}_F
\end{equation}
where:

- $R$ is a rotation matrix (${R}^T R = I_N$),
- $\| . {\|}_F$ is the   Frobenius norm and $X$,
- $Y$ is the matrix representation of $\{x_i\}_{i=1..n}$ and $\{y_i\}_{i=1..n}$.

**Question:** Knowing that the distribution of the random variable $x$ which generates each $x_i$ is multivariate Gaussian, is there any theoretical garentees about the distribution of the estimated vectors $\hat{y}_i$ using this algorithm ?

**Attempt:** I have doubts about this since the procedure is not Bayesian and there is no use of prior knowledge about the distribution of the target random variable $p(x)$. But I don't know whether this information is "implicitly" accounted for in the model.